# ML lemma to show that $\left|\int_\Gamma \frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(z^2+1)^2} \ dz\right|\rightarrow 0$ (indented contour)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to compute the real integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{(x^2+1)^2} \ dz,$$ by computing the contour integral$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(z^2+1)^2} \ dz, \ \ \ \text{where $\frac{-\pi}{2}<\text{Arg}\leq\frac{3\pi}{2}$}$$

I have computed both the lines from $-R$ to $-r$ and $r$ to $R$ shown on the diagram below. However, I am having trouble computing the circular regions via the ML Lemma ($r<1<R$).

For the half-circle with radius $R$, I have tried:
\begin{align}
\text{let} \  z&=Re^{it} \ \ t\in [0,\pi] \\
\implies |z|&=R \\
\text{consider} \ |z^2+1|&\geq ||z^2|-|-1|| \\
\frac{1}{|(z^2+1)^2|}&\leq\frac{1}{(R^2-1)^2} \\
\left|\frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\right|&\leq\frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(R^2-1)^2}
\end{align}

But does $$\frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(R^2-1)^2} \times R\pi\rightarrow 0\ \text{as} \ R\rightarrow\infty?$$

$\hskip2in$[image]
**update**

I have solved the integral, with a lot of help from the comments section; thanks! But my proof requires that the inner cirlce with radius $r$ is $0$: $$\left|\frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\right|\leq \frac{\ln(r)-i\pi}{(1-r^2)^2}\rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ r\rightarrow 0.$$
I have used the ML Lemma, but I do not know how to evaluate this limit (it does not appear to be in indeterminate form, hence L'Hopital's rule does not apply). How do I evaluate the limit (or show the contour of the inner circle is $0$ using the ML lemma)?

Comment: For $z=Re^{it}$, $$ \left| \frac{\operatorname{Log}(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\right| \leq \frac{2\pi + \log R}{(R^2-1)^2}. $$

Comment: Does $i$Arg($z)=2\pi$?

Comment: OP: $2\pi$ is the largest the argument can be given your range (in fact, you can bound it by $\pi$, but the point is moot as $\log R$ dominates the constant).

Comment: Only the estimation of the integral on the semicircle subpath(s) of radius $R$ (and $r$ is the problem)? It is maybe / arguably simpler to consider the integral obtained after substituting $u=\log z$, $$J=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac u{(e^{2u}+1)^2}\; e^u\; du\ ,$$ then consider the rectangular path with vertices $-R$, $+R$, $+R+i\pi$, $-R+i\pi$. The two integrals on the "long segments" are converging to $2J$ plus purely imaginary contribution, there is only one  pole in $i\pi/2$ with residue $\pi/8+i/4$ . So $2\pi\; i(\pi/8+i/4)=2J+i\Bbb R$. So $J=-\pi/4$.

Comment: @Clayton Could Arg($z)=\pi$? Hence $\text{Log}(z)=\ln(R)+i\pi$. To me, this makes more sense as we're considering $z=Re^{it}$ where $t\in [0,\pi]$. It is a minor point (either way, the integral converges to $0$), but i'd like to understand this if possible :)

Comment: Bell: You can only bound it above by $\pi$. The argument actually ranges from $0$ to $\pi$, so the best you can do is bound it above by a constant (which is $\pi$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach: for any $s\in(-1,3)$, by the substitution $x\mapsto\tan\theta$ and Euler's Beta function we have

$$ f(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi(1-s)}{4\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4}(1-s)(1+O(s^2))$$
hence by differentiating both sides with respect to $s$
$$ f'(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx = -\frac{\pi}{8\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}\left[2-\pi\tan\left(\tfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)+\pi s\tan\left(\tfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)\right] $$
and the Maclaurin series of the RHS is $\color{red}{-\frac{\pi}{4}}+\frac{\pi^3}{16}s+O(s^2)$.

---

Even shorter: by the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ we have $f(s)=f(2-s)$, and by integration by parts $\frac{f(s)}{1-s}$ is an even function. In particular $f'(0)$ (which is the wanted integral) simply equals 
$$-f(0)=-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=-\frac{\pi}{4}.$$