# What is the correct technique to integrate logarithms on paths on the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I will use the following integral as a dummy exercise.

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2} dx
\end{equation}

I thought that the correct way to compute this kind of integrals (even when the logarithm has exponent $a\neq 1$) is to take the limit for $R\to\infty$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$ of the integral given by:

\begin{equation}
\int_\Gamma \frac{\ln z}{(1+z^2)^2} dz
\end{equation}

defining $\Gamma \equiv \gamma_1 + \gamma_R + \gamma_2 + \gamma_\varepsilon$, where:

- $\gamma_1(t)=t$, $t\in[0,R]$
- $\gamma_R(t) = Re^{2i\pi t}$, $t\in[0,1]$
- $\gamma_2(t)=-t$, $t\in[0,R]$
- $\gamma_\varepsilon(t) = \varepsilon e^{-2\pi i t}$, $t\in[0,1]$

This choice comes from defining the logarithm's branch cut on the positive real axis and building a path that does not cycle around the diramation point $z=0$ nor crosses the branch cut. Of course, by the Residue Theorem, the value of the integral will be: $2\pi i \sum_{j}\text{Res}(f,a_j)$, where $\{a_j\}$ are the singularities inside $\Gamma$

To hopefully clear things out:

\begin{align}
\left( \int_{\gamma_R} +\int_{\gamma_1} + \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} + \int_{\gamma_2} \right) f(z) \, dz &= 2\pi i \sum_{j} \text{Res}(f,a_j) \\
\implies \left( \int_{\gamma_1} + \int_{\gamma_2} \right) f(z) \, dz &= \left( -\int_{\gamma_R} - \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \right) f(z) \, dz + 2\pi i \sum_{j} \text{Res}(f,a_j)
\end{align}

The integrals on the left are the ones that I wanted to compute at the beginning, but the important terms cancel out, because the only difference between numbers on the two paths is a phase: $\ln(ze^{2\pi i}) = \ln(z) + 2\pi i$.

What am I missing?

***Edit:** as kindly suggested in the comments, the integral I wrote above has been already solved. I think that answer that fits best with my question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2290340/1278563), because it follows each step clearly and suggests a general approach to logarithm integrals.*

Comment: On $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, the integrand is undefined when $t=0$

Comment: You need to integrate $\log^2{z}$ around the contour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a definite integral using residue theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024977/evaluating-a-definite-integral-using-residue-theorem) or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986570 See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290308, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271097, [etc.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%20x%7D%7B(1%2Bx%5E2)%5E2%7D%20dx%24&p=2)

Comment: @Anne Bauval yes! Thank you very much, I didn't know this integral has been done countless times. I couldn't seem to find anything like it. What's the next step? Do I answer my own question or delete my post?

Comment: You should not answer it, but you don't need to delete it. Users with 3000 reputation will vote to close it as a duplicate and link to some previous such post(s).